# How to have my app in "Open with..." with iOS

Tags: ios

When we view a photo, pdf, or any other files on iOS, it is possible to open the file in another app by clicking on "Open with...". And I would like to have my app in the list, for PDF files, PNG and JPEG.
I have tried everything I found on Google, and here is my file info.plist :

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
            <array/>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>PDF</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Owner</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.adobe.pdf</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
            <array/>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>PNG</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Owner</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.png</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
            <array/>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>JPG</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Owner</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.jpg</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

I have tried to change it with all I found on Internet, but my app never appears in the list.

Is there something else to do than modifying the file info.plist ?

Actually, I manage to open PDF file in my App only in SAFARI ! But it's not as I want :
[image]

When I view a PDF File in safari, I can see on the top "Open with", but on all other apps when I click on the button Open with, I can't see my app.

What I would like is this :

[image]

Thank you very much for your help :D

Regards

Comment: FYI - your app isn't the owner of these types. Change "Owner" to "Alternate". But that is a side note, not a fix. Did you try with a PDF attachment in an email? Does that work? Get that working first.

Comment: No unfortunately, it still doesn't work, BUT in Safari I can see "Open with..." but it's not in where I want it... I have added details in my post :). Thanks !